# Nested if statements: Swapping headers and sequences in fasta files

Tags: perl, if-statement, while-loop, nested

I am opening a directory and processing each file. A sample file looks like this when opened:

```
>AAAAA
TTTTTTTTTTTAAAAATTTTTTTTTT
>BBBBB
TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTBBBBBTTT
>CCCCC
TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTCCCCCTTTTT
```

For the above sample file, I am trying to make them look like this:

```
>TAAAAAT 
AAAAA
>TBBBBBT 
BBBBB
>TCCCCCT 
CCCCC
```

I need to find the "header" in next line sequence, take flanks on either side of the match, and then flip them. I want to print each file's worth of contents to another separate file. 
Here is my code so far. It runs without errors, but doesn't generate any output. My guess is this is probably related to the nested if statements. I have never worked with those before.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict; 
use warnings; 

my ($directory) = @ARGV;
my $dir = "$directory";
my @ArrayofFiles = glob "$dir/*";
my $count = 0; 

open(OUT, ">", "/path/to/output_$count.txt") or die $!; 

foreach my $file(@ArrayofFiles){
    open(my $fastas, $file) or die $!;
    while (my $line = <$fastas>){
        $count++;
        if ($line =~ m/(^>)([a-z]{5})/i){
            my $header = $2;
            if ($line !~ /^>/){
                my $sequence .= $line;
                if ($sequence =~ m/(([a-z]{1})($header)([a-z]{1}))/i){
                    my $matchplusflanks = $1;
                    print OUT ">", $matchplusflanks, "\n", $header, "\n";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I fix this code? Thanks.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the feedback. I will clean this up!

Comment: Let me know if I can make this question better! Thanks

Comment: I was more thinking to something more realistic like:`>RESTG` with `MTEITAAMVKELRESTGAGMMDCKNA` that gives `>LRESTGA` and `RESTG`. *(this way people understands that a cat isn't jumping on the keyboard and that letters are not random. You can see immediately from where comes the letters around)*.

Comment: My modification should clear things up now. Is there anything else I can do to improve this question? Thanks.

Comment: What is the goal of the `$count` var? Do you want to produce an output file for each file with the number of lines (or the number or `>`) in the name? What if two files have the same number of lines?

Comment: I included the count only to differentiate the file names. It has no relation to the file contents.

Comment: It's most common to see *snake_case_identifiers* in Perl code. It is much more readable, especially for people whose first language isn't English (and so the capital letters don't stand out for them), and programmers familiar with Perl will thank you. But if you do decide to go for *camelCaseIdentifiers* then please use an initial lower-case letter for all lexical variables and subroutines. Capital initials are reserved for package-wide identifiers such as `Package::Names` or `use constant VALUES`.

Comment: Hi Borodin. Thanks for the feedback. Is that in reference to my array name, @ArrayofFiles? I can change that to @files, like Casimir et Hippolyte did below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
foreach my $file(@ArrayofFiles)
{
    open my $fh," <", $file or die"error opening $!\n";
    while(my $head=<$fh>)
    {
        chomp $head;
        $head=~s/>//;
        my $next_line = <$fh>;
        my($extract) = $next_line =~m/(.$head.)/;
        print ">$extract\n$head\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several mistakes in your code but the main problem is:

```
if ($line =~ m/(^>)([a-z]{5})/i) {
    my $header = $2;
    if ($line !~ /^>/) {
        # here you write to the output file
```

Because the same line can't start and **not** start with `>` at the same time, your output files are never written. The second `if` statement always fails and its block is never executed.

`open(OUT, ">", "/path/to/output_$count.txt") or die $!;` and `$count++` are misplaced. Since you want to produce an output file (with a new name) for each input file, you need to put them in the `foreach` block, not outside or in the while loop.

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($dir) = @ARGV;
my @files = glob "$dir/*";
my $count;
my $format = ">%s\n%s\n";

foreach my $file (@files) {
    open my $fhi, '<', $file
        or die "Can't open file '$file': $!";

    $count++;
    my $output_path = "/path/to/output_$count.txt";

    open my $fho, '>', $output_path
        or die "Can't open file '$output_path': $!";

    my ($header, $seq);

    while(<$fhi>) {
       chomp;
       if (/^>([a-z]{5})/i) {
          if ($seq) { printf $fho $format, $seq =~ /([a-z]$header[a-z])/i, $header; }
          ($header, $seq) = ($1, '');
       } else { $seq .= $_; }
    }
    if ($seq) { printf $fho $format, $seq =~ /([a-z]$header[a-z])/i, $header; }
}

close $fhi;
close $fho;
```

Comment: Why are you passing strings by reference to `getflanks`?

Comment: @Borodin: I wanted to prevent a copy of the variable content when I assign `@_`. But perhaps it's more easy to use `$_[n]` directly or there's another way?

Comment: In your original code, `my ($refheader, $refseq) = @_` makes copies of the parameters anyway, so the original values are safe. But `return $refseq =~ /([a-z]$refheader[a-z])/i` doesn't modify anything anyway so there is nothing to protect against. Note that `getflanks` must be called in list context, otherwise it will return a boolean value indicating the success of the match, probably `1`.

Comment: @Borodin: The goal wasn't to protect the variables, but to avoid the copy of the variable content. In my previous code `my ($refheader, $refseq) = @_` makes copies of references only, not copies of the "header" and a possibly long sequence. The goal of `getflanks` isn't to be reused in an eventual other place in the code *(it is always used in list context)*. I created it only to not overwrite the capture group 1 *(from the previous if condition)*, but there's probably a more simple way to do that.